# Como usar Elevation?

Tags: android

Fui utilizar o elevation para testar , porém inseri ele no XML de um botão e não mudou a elevação dele , se puderem me ajudar , obrigado desde já

Comment: Cadê o código que está usando? Elevação em que? Toolbar? Relative? Tem como detalhar melhor?

Comment: @paiva suas perguntas ja foram negativadas inumeras vezes, recomendo ler http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

caso continue a fazer perguntas mal fundamentadas, poderá ser punido  como dito aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-limited
Apenas um dica, todos estão aqui pra ajudar... mas pra te ajudar precisamos que voce ajude a todos também!

Comment: Paiva, conseguiu resolver o problema?! Eu até sei fazer isso, mas não sei o que você tentou fazer. Coloque aqui o que você tentou.

Comment: @AckLay             <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="teste"
    android:elevation="10dp"/>

Comment: Utilizei um botão e no xml dele coloquei elevation="10dp" , porém não muda nada ao testar no celular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O atributo `elevation` somente terá algum efeito se você estiver usando API level 21 ou superior. Veja qui algumas dicas sobre [Elevation & shadows](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#).

De acordo as [especificações do Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html), cada componente tem seu [limite ideal](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android) de elevação, como por exemplo o `Button` que tem por padrão `8dp`.

No seu caso, o que pode estar acontecendo é que as propriedades padrões do botão está sobrescrevendo as suas. Se você definir essa elevação de `10dp`, por exemplo para um `LinearLayout`, certamente funcionará.

Veja um exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:background="#f0f0f0"
        android:elevation="16sp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>**Nota**: Aconselho fortemente você seguir as [recomendações do Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/material-design/elevation-shadows.html) quanto a elevações e sombreamentos, para que possa continuar com a mesma elegância.</sup>